# Eclipse freeze after importing google play library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I try to add google play library to my project for google maps.
I downloaded the google play extras from the sdk manager, imported it to my workspace and added it to my project in the project properties.
after adding the library when i launch the app eclipse freezes with 99% launch.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you using ADT or Eclipse?

Comment: Use ADT http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Is your device currently connected to the USB port?

Comment: Yes,I installed the adt from this link:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
but its still not working.

Comment: Please download `Android studio` for Android development because `Eclipse` will no longer maintain by Google. Also you can `set up google play service` for the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Already done this,works fine in studio